# split list into sublists

Tags: python, split

> Define a function `split_list` that takes in a list of numbers and a number `a` and splits it into two sublists: `list1` that contains numbers smaller than or equal to `a`, and another list, `list2` containing numbers greater than a. `list1` and `list2` must be returned as elements of a tuple.

My code:

```
def split_list(lst, a):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for i in lst:
        if i <= a:
            list1.append(i)
            lst.remove(i)
        elif i > a:
            list2.append(i)
            lst.remove(i)
    return (list1, list2)
```

Test code:

```
split_list([1, 10, 4, 9, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 9, 6, 2], 5)
```

should give: `([1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2], [10, 9, 7, 8, 9, 6])`

But I got `([1, 4, 5, 3, 2], [7, 9])` instead. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't remove from `lst`; there is no need to and it causes your loop to skip every second item.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Martijn, you're breaking your list `lst` by trying to iterate through it and remove from it at the same time.

You don't need to remove from `lst`, so you can remove those lines.

Or, you could iterate over a *copy* of `lst`, whilst removing from the original `lst`.
To do this, simply change your for loop to be:

```
for i in lst[:]
```

This will copy a slice corresponding to the whole of `lst` for you to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid skipping elements you can alternatively loop through the list backwards deleting as you go.  Here's an example using list indexes instead of the "for listitem in list" construct.

```
def split_list(lst, a):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for x in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):
        if lst[x] <= a:
            list1.append(lst[x])
            del lst[x]
        elif lst[x] > a:
            list2.append(lst[x])
            del lst[x]
    return (list1, list2)

print split_list([1, 10, 4, 9, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 9, 6, 2], 5)    

# outputs ([2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1], [6, 9, 8, 7, 9, 10])
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a `list` while iterating over it is always going to end badly. I would do instead:

```
for i in lst[:]:  # Make a shallow copy.
    #stuff
```

We are then iterating over that unmodified copy, so based on this we can edit the original safely.

Or just don't modify the list at all, meaning you can remove all uses of `lst.remove(i)` which should also fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_list(lst, a):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for i in lst:
        if i <= a:
            list1.append(i)

        elif i > a:
            list2.append(i)

    return (list1, list2)
```

There's no need to remove the items from the lst list as you iterate through it.

Comment: Simply spitting out working code to an asker is not how this site works. Nobody learns when they are spoon-fed information.

Comment: Thanks Alex, good point. I've updated the post.